# Computer Graphics: Draw a triangle by my own

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

Recently I'm studying the computer graphics with OpenGL, but I have a question is that if I can draw something totally without OpenGL, DirecX, etc. 
In other words, Can I draw a triangle all by my own?  Not just specifying the vertices, then run the right function.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @Beginner I think it's a bit difficult to give a good answer to this question. Either the answer is just "Yes, you can - cf. OpenGL implementation" which is technically correct, but not very helpful to the OP, or it's going to be "Yes, you can" followed by a copy-paste of an introductory book about Computer Graphics. The way I understood this question was beyond "How to color a pixel in a window" but rather "How to render a 3D scene without the use of OpenGL". If the former was meant by OP, the question should have been rephrased in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe I did not ask a good question. In fact, I'm just wondering  what happened when I call the function to draw a triangle.

Comment: @Ico826: To paraphrase in two words (and quoting Neil Stephenson's "Snow Crash" upon what happens when the Deliverator puts the pedal to the metal) what happens when you do the innocent looking call of `glDraw…`: "shit happens!" – Graphics drivers are incredibly complex beasts, something on the order of 50 million lines of code in current implementations. And that's not counting all the stuff the operating system kernel does in addition to that to support things like high speed memory to peripheral bus transfers (DMA).

Comment: @Ico826: In very general, broad terms what happens is, that a batch of OpenGL command calls (the calls, not the shaders!) is literally compiled into a sequence of command the graphics hardware understands and which execution sets the outline for the actual rasterization process. Then the driver fills in a bunch of buffers with the actual drawing parameters (like position of the vertices). Also modern GPUs require shaders and depending on the OpenGL state the selected shader may be modified/recompiled. Once that's done everything is packed up and DMAed over to the GPU.

Comment: @Ico826: What then happens on the GPU is essentially what also happens rasterizers you can implement in software. Only that some parts of that are hardwired on the GPU metal. Other parts are actually executed computer programs (the shaders).

Comment: @Ico826 I did not mean to intend that your question was bad - in fact, I don't think it is, as some pretty interesting and amazing stuff is going on behind the scenes as datenwolf says. Unfortunately it's just a kind of question that is not very suitable for Stackoverflow as I tried to point out with my comment. Feel free to read through the Asking Helpcenter (http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to clarify things up for you.

Comment: @Ico826: To answer your question: If all you have at hand is just a high level programming language without the notion of low level hardware access, the best you can do it rasterize to some buffer in memory, but there's no way to display it. You need some kind of low level hardware access to do that. Either by making use of some operating system or hardware access library level interface, *or* by writing those parts in assembly (thereby essentially implementing this kind of access library yourself).

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for your answer. I think you have explained the things clear to me! It's really a tons of things to do!

Comment: @kaufmanu:  To be honest,I'm a beginner of Stackoverflow, so thank you for pointing out this question is not suitable for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Note that in addition to the excellent information datenwolf provided, there is also ample material out there on software rendering. If you like to draw content without the interference of a graphics API, nothing stops you from setting up some drawing surface and using standard algorithms to draw your triangles/lines/whatnot pixel by pixel. And it's actually pretty informative to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course you can. You can ask the window manager of your OS to give you access to the pixels of your window and directly color the pixels of inside the window pane.

Here's [some C code](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=269406) that draws 25000 (NPTS) random black pixels in a window XRESxYRES, compile with 'gcc -lX11 -o x1 x1.c' , execute with './x1 &'

```
//----- x1.c simple xwindows example -----

#include <X11/Xlib.h> // must precede most other headers!
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void update_screen();

int XRES=500;
int YRES=500;
int NPTS=25000;

//Need this array if we're plotting all at once using XDrawPoints
//XPoint pts[NPTS];

Display *dsp;
Window win;
GC gc;

int main(){

  dsp = XOpenDisplay( NULL );
  if( !dsp ){ return 1; }

  int screen = DefaultScreen(dsp);
  unsigned int white = WhitePixel(dsp,screen);
  unsigned int black = BlackPixel(dsp,screen);

  win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dsp,
                            DefaultRootWindow(dsp),
                            0, 0,   // origin
                            XRES, YRES, // size
                            0, black, // border width/clr
                            white);   // backgrd clr


  Atom wmDelete=XInternAtom(dsp, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", True);
  XSetWMProtocols(dsp, win, &wmDelete, 1);

  gc = XCreateGC(dsp, win,
                 0,       // mask of values
                 NULL);   // array of values

  XSetForeground(dsp, gc, black);

  XEvent evt;
  long eventMask = StructureNotifyMask;
  eventMask |= ButtonPressMask|ButtonReleaseMask|KeyPressMask|KeyReleaseMask;
  XSelectInput(dsp, win, eventMask);

  KeyCode keyQ;
  keyQ = XKeysymToKeycode(dsp, XStringToKeysym("Q"));

  XMapWindow(dsp, win);

  // wait until window appears
  do { XNextEvent(dsp,&evt); } while (evt.type != MapNotify);

  srand(time(0)); // only 1 sec resolution so use once per run
  update_screen();

  int loop = 1;

  while (loop) {
    // for repeated fine seeding use:
    // struct timeval ti
    // gettimeofday(&ti,NULL);
    // srand((ti.tv_sec * 1000) + (ti.tv_usec / 1000));

    XNextEvent(dsp, &evt);

    switch (evt.type) {

      case (ButtonRelease) :

        update_screen();
        break;

      case (KeyRelease) :

        if (evt.xkey.keycode == keyQ) loop = 0;
        else update_screen();
        break;

      case (ConfigureNotify) :

        // Check if window has been resized
        if (evt.xconfigure.width != XRES || evt.xconfigure.height != YRES)
        {
          XRES = evt.xconfigure.width;
          YRES = evt.xconfigure.height;
          update_screen();
        }
        break;

      case (ClientMessage) :

        if (evt.xclient.data.l[0] == wmDelete) loop = 0;
        break;

      default :

        break;
    }
  } 

  XDestroyWindow(dsp, win);
  XCloseDisplay(dsp);

  return 0;
}

void update_screen()
{
  XClearWindow(dsp, win);

  XDrawLine(dsp, win, gc, 0, YRES/2, XRES-1, YRES/2); //from-to
  XDrawLine(dsp, win, gc, XRES/2, 0, XRES/2, YRES-1); //from-to

  long i;
  for (i=0; i<NPTS; i++) {
    XDrawPoint(dsp, win, gc, rand()%XRES, rand()%YRES);
    //pts[i].x = rand()%XRES;
    //pts[i].y = rand()%YRES;
  }

  //XClearWindow(dsp,win);
  //XDrawPoints(dsp, win, gc, pts, NPTS, CoordModeOrigin);

  return;
}
```

Comment: I think this still doesn't qualify as "on your own" in terms of OP's question.

Comment: @datenwolf you got a point. There's a hierarchy here.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, you can draw a triangle all by yourself, without requiring an external library. Of course, in order to do that, you will find yourself replicating an entire rendering pipeline. Writing a renderer that both produces correct results and is efficient and versatile is far from being an easy task. Still, this might be a valuable thing to do for educational purposes, but I would still suggest to go ahead and learn how to use OpenGL (or any other library/framework you deem worthy for your task) instead of putting hours and hours into trying to find out why your self-made renderer produces this one tiny artefact.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, drawing a triangle just means coloring in a lot of pixels. With current screens, that might be a million pixels.

But a standard C++ exercise is to draw a triangle with characters, e.g.

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
```

Sure, your console may have a rather limited resolution, but the basic algorithm can be pretty much the same. Have a go, and start with the simple example above. Then, to make it harder for yourself, let the user input 3 points `x,y` and use those as corner points. Since it's text, you'd test with small values of `x` and `y`, but that's just details.

Comment: Drawing a triangle with * characters is a perfectly valid exercise, especially if only vertex coordinates are given. Before downvoting: how would you do this efficiently given`(x_1, y_1, z_1), ..., (x_3, y_3, z_3)`? One day someone has to explain the downvote frenzy around here.